# Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Selenium.
Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157
Getting error:
`"Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process"`
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p5gZ.png)

Code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157

Comment: That should be fine. Can you check if you have chrome set to “run as administrator”? That could break chromedriver I think.

Comment: Chrome is NOT set to run as administrator.

Comment: looks like no one can help